# Sum values of a coulmn in specific rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to learn how to specify a "subset-sum" in a dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

[image]

The Data/Time column is the dataframes' index

With

```
Sum = data['A'].sum()
```

I get the total sum of column A.

My aim is to sum up a subset of rows only like between 2022-03-18 07:37:51 and 2022-03-18 07:37:55

so that I get a "sum" row:

[image]

How can I specify the row numbers to be summed for each column, especially when the index is in datetime format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data[(data.index >= '2020-01-01 00:00:16') & (data.index <= '2020-01-01 00:00:17')].sum(axis=0)
```

simply, use axis = 0 for each coulmn sum, and check by a.index >= '2020-01-01 00:00:16' and equivalent for upper bound

**if you want to use datetime module:**

```
from datetime import datetime
data[(data.index >= datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 16)) & (data.index <= datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 17))].sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: the first proposal leads to the type error: TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and str. The second leads to always the same result independend which time stamp I give. The same result whether its the sum over only one second over 4000. .... Another idea? Could I also use the column names directly instead of axis=0?

Comment: @Swawa if index is str, please use **data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)** for convertion before first proposal or second, and dont use column name is sum method because that do, itself

Comment: @Swawa I think your usage of second proposal is incorrect: datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 16)), please write your usage, there if you can

Comment: If I use `data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
print(data.index)
HistBin = data[(data.index >= '2022-03-018 07:37:49') & (data.index <= '2022-03-18 07:37:51')].sum(axis=0) `  I get strange result like `DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-18 07:37:46', '2022-03-18 07:37:47',
               '2022-03-18 07:37:48', '2022-03-18 07:37:49',
               '2022-03-18 07:37:50', '2022-03-18 07:37:51',
               '2022-03-18 07:37:52', '2022-03-18 07:37:53',
               '2022-03-18 07:37:54', '2022-03-18 07:37:55',`

Comment: @Swawa ok it is output of **print(data.index)** and i think it it correct, what is output of **print(HistBin)**?

Comment: I still get TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and str

Comment: @Swawa it is incorrect: 2022-03-018, please remove zero that is before 18

Comment: ok, this is working now `data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data.HistBin = data[(data.index >= '2022-03-18 07:37:49') & (data.index <= '2022-03-18 07:37:51')].sum(axis=0)` but it's in a column. using `data.HistBin = data.HistBin.transpose()` does not transpose it to a row

Comment: @Swawa **pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(data.HistBin.index.to_list(),[[i] for i in data.HistBin])))**

Comment: @Swawa if it was your answer, please accept it, if not, please ask me

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more generic criterion to select rows, not only time ranges then you could work with this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[12,5,7], [13,7,4], [14,7,23], [15,71,9], [16,5,4], [17,55,42]], columns=['T', 'A', 'B'])

print(df)
    T   A   B
0  12   5   7
1  13   7   4
2  14   7  23
3  15  71   9
4  16   5   4
5  17  55  42

range_idx = df['T'].between(13,15) # or another selection
df[range_idx]

    T   A   B
1   13  7   4
2   14  7   23
3   15  71  9

df[range_idx][['A','B']].sum()

Out[42]:
A    85
B    36
```

Comment: the sum is not working for me. I always get the Type error that there is no cloumn named 'A' or which ever I choose.

Comment: sorry, a [ ] was misapplied. this is working in principle except that it is not using the time stamp index

Comment: Sure, you fix the timestamp thingy. I just used a quic&dirty index.